# how can i execute console command

Tags: lightning, console

I trying to handling DOM Element in Lightning component.

because of `aura:id` need literal value,
 i can't use `find().getElement()` in `<aura:iteration>`.

and i attempted to console command. like below and it works.( in browser )

```
=> document.getElementByClassName('foo')
```

so i want this code bring into controller.js Script.

how can i apply this command to my lightning component?
it just print as plain text

```
console.log('var iconList = document.getElementsByClassName(\'foo\');');
```

thanks.

---

[ Edit for code snippets ]

There is UserOrGroupId Field in Sharing Object.

i want only User Id for this Field. so i trying to partially disable `<force:inputField>`  by group icon disable.

> > .cmp file

```
<aura:component description="SharingComponentList">
   <aura:attribute  name="sharingList"  type="sObject[]" access="public"/>
   <aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.afterRendering}"/>

   <aura:iteration items="{!v.sharingList}" var="sharing">
      <force:inputField value="{!v.sharing.UserOrGroupId}" required="true"/>
       ....
   </aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

> > .js file

```
afterRendering : function(component,event,helper){
    console.log('var iconList = document.getElementsByClassName(\'deleteIcon\');');
}
```

Comment: Hi @byeon can you share code snippets for .cmp and .js files.
It's very difficult to get what exactly you need. Please give more context

Comment: Hi @pranav prashant . im attached code snippet to question..thanks

Comment: @byeon I do not understand an issue since you always have <force:inputField value="{!v.sharing.UserOrGroupId}" required="true"/> why don't you just take it out of iteration?